# animation in angular, hide/show specific div for x number of seconds

Tags: angular, angular-material, material-design, css-animations, angular8

I have a angular page whose design is like this.

[image]

The value `1022` comes from socket events which are handled in component, it keeps on changing after some time.

What I need is, when I get any new value I update it, but after update it should be like flash in out, hide/show for x number of seconds.
I can do such thing using css but that occurs only once, I need it on every update and also don't want to use jQuery in it. pure angular, css, material design only.

> In short, I need a function in component which will get parameter seconds, and
>   when called it will make token div hide/show, hide/show slowly for
>   that number of seconds passed.

My component is

```
export class CounterdisplayComponent implements OnInit {

  cdID = '';
  dataSource: Tokens = {token: '', counter: '', finish: false};
  constructor(
    private socketService: CounterSocketService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute
  ) {
    const params = this.route.snapshot.params;
    this.cdID = params.id;

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.connectSockets();
  }

  connectSockets(): void {
    const THIS = this;
    this.socketService.initSocket( this.cdID );

    this.socketService.onMessage()
    .subscribe((message: Tokens) => {
      console.log('update ', message);
      if ( !message.finish ) {
        console.log('Got data => ', message);
        this.dataSource = message;
      } else {
        // THIS.removeToken( message );
      }
    });

  }

  removeToken( tokenObj ): void {
    this.dataSource = {token: '', counter: '', finish: false};
  }

}
```

The onMessage subscriber keeps on giving callback for data,
My html file is very simeple like this.

```
<div id="counterdisplay">
    <div class="counter">
        <p>Counter  </p>
        <p class="value">
            <span *ngIf="dataSource.counter != ''" >
                    {{ dataSource.counter }}
            </span>
            <span *ngIf="dataSource.counter == ''" >
                    -----
            </span>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="token">
        <p>Now Serving  </p>
        <p class="value">
            <span *ngIf="dataSource.token != ''">{{ dataSource.token }}</span>
            <span *ngIf="dataSource.token == ''">-----</span>
        </p>
    </div>

  </div>
```

Comment: will you please add code snippen what you have done so far

Comment: i have updated the questions with code, kindly check now.

Answer (score 1):

**Component:**

```
import { trigger, state, style, transition, animate } from '@angular/animations';

...

@Component({
  selector: 'componente',
  templateUrl: './componente.html',
  styleUrls: ['./componente.css'],
  animations: [
    trigger('esvanecerDesvanecer', [
      state('in', style({ opacity: 1 })),

      transition(':enter', [
        style({ opacity: 0 }),
        animate(400)
      ]),

      transition(':leave',
        animate(200, style({ opacity: 0 })))
    ])      
  ]
})
```

**HTML:**

```
<div [@esvanecerDesvanecer]="'in'">
```

Answer (score 1):

```
setInterval(() => {
  // write pure JavaScript here that will work
 }, 2000);
```

Try this, hope it will work for you.

Comment: using this, i can only hide/show, it will not add any animation like hide slowly and show slowly etc